# Webview in VSCode Web Extensions?

Tags: vscode-extensions

Is it possible to use the webview [API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview) in a VSCode [web extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/web-extensions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, webviews work in web extensions. Made a silly mistake when testing.

Comment: what does the "silly mistake" means?

Comment: In my case, I forgot to rebuild it with webpack, so I was running an invalid version. In standard VSCode there was no need for this step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the webview in vscode extensions.
Here's the link to the sample extension:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/webview-view-sample